# Apply Models from Nested Resample to Permuted Dataset

Tags: mlr3

I have generated a nested resampling object with the following code:

```
data<-read.csv("Data.csv", row.names=1)

data$factor<-as.factor(data$factor)

set.seed(123, "L'Ecuyer")

task = as_task_classif(data, target = "factor")

learner = lrn("classif.ranger", importance = "impurity", num.trees=10000)

measure = msr("classif.fbeta", beta=1)

terminator = trm("none")

resampling_inner = rsmp("repeated_cv", folds = 10, repeats = 10)

at = AutoFSelector$new(
  learner = learner,
  resampling = resampling_inner,
  measure = measure,
  terminator = terminator,
  fselect = fs("rfe", n_features = 1, feature_fraction = 0.5, recursive = FALSE),
  store_models = TRUE)

resampling_outer = rsmp("repeated_cv", folds = 10, repeats = 10)

rr = resample(task, at, resampling_outer)
```

I have a .csv file with the factor variable permuted/randomized and would like to apply the models of the nested resampling paradigm to this dataset so I can demonstrated differences in the model performance between the real dataset and the permuted/randomized dataset. I am interested in this to validate predictive performance because when sample sizes are small (which is common in biological contexts) prediction accuracy by chance alone can approach 70% or higher based on this paper (https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/25596422/).

How would I do this using the resample object (rr)?

Answer (score 2):

I think I figured out how to do it (do let me know if I went wrong somewhere):

```
data<-read.csv("Data.csv", row.names=1)

data$factor<-as.factor(data$factor)

permuted<-read.csv("Data.csv", row.names=1)

permuted$factor<-as.factor(permuted$factor)

set.seed(123, "L'Ecuyer")

task1 = as_task_classif(data, target = "factor")

task2 = as_task_classif(permuted, target = "factor")

task_list = list(task1, task2)

learner = lrn("classif.ranger", importance = "impurity", num.trees=10000)

measure = msr("classif.fbeta", beta=1)

terminator = trm("none")

resampling_inner = rsmp("repeated_cv", folds = 10, repeats = 10)

at = AutoFSelector$new(
  learner = learner,
  resampling = resampling_inner,
  measure = measure,
  terminator = terminator,
  fselect = fs("rfe", n_features = 1, feature_fraction = 0.5, recursive = FALSE),
  store_models = TRUE)

resampling_outer = rsmp("repeated_cv", folds = 10, repeats = 10)

design = benchmark_grid(task=task_list, learner=at, resampling=resampling_outer)

bmr = benchmark(design, store_models = TRUE)
```

Comment: Is not an answer, place the update into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Am I right in assuming that you have two tasks `t1` and `t2`, where the task `t2` is permuted and you wanted to compare the performance of a learner on these two tasks?

The way to go then is to use the `benchmark()` function instead of the `resample` function. You would have to create two different tasks (one permuted and one not permuted).
You might find the section [Resampling and Benchmarking](https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/performance.html) in our book helpful.

Comment: Yeah this sounds like what I want to do. Can I feed a nested resample call into the benchmark function? I was reading and unsure how to build the benchmark grid using the AutoFSelector with inner resampling and outer resampling like my code above with the resample command.